# How do I get reference to an application in a bluetooth service?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to use requestPermissions() in my bluetooth service but I can't seem to get an activity reference in my service and I've heard that is bad practice to do so anyways, so how can I use requestPermissions within my bluetooth service?

Here is my bluetooth service connection code:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    fun connect(device: BluetoothDevice): Boolean {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_CHECK_BT_PERMISSION)
        bluetoothAdapter?.let {
            return try {
                // Connect to devices gatt server.
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(--ACTIVITY_NEEDED_HERE--, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT), 1)
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return true
                }
                bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(applicationContext, false, gattCallback)
                true
            } catch (exception: IllegalArgumentException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Device not found with provided address.")
                false
            }
            // connect to the GATT server on the device
        } ?: run {
            Log.d(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized")
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Primarily, request the permission before starting the service, or consider whether you really need a service. If your service winds up running without the permission, raise a `Notification`, and request the permission when the member taps on the notification to display your activity.

Comment: I agree with CommonsWare. Android suggests asking for permission before you use a feature that needs it so that the user can still use the rest of the app if they do not want to give that particular permission. No need to ask for it inside your service

Comment: @CommonsWare I appreciate your answers! I had never considered that. I will definitely move it out of my service!